# How to download file from the web with Powershell when url redirects

Tags: powershell, webclient

I have seen downloading a file with the webclient for powershell.  Problem is that the request url redirects multiple times before the actual file is presented.  it's an ssrs web interface with a query string meathod Download=bla.csv

any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: looks like they hid the request behind some soap request

Comment: the web request returns a webpage with a form that autosubmits.  Can I have powershell submit that form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [this script](http://poshcode.org/2767) on poshcode.org or try to take hints using `System.Net.CookieContainer` to avoid falling in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario where my URL is redirected and then we need to download the file. What I did was get the redirected URL and parse for the http address and again invoked with the redirected URL. Below code worked for me.

```
$username = "u"
$password = "p"
$auth=$username+":"+$password
$Encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
$EncodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Encoded)
$latestArtifactURL = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $EncodedPassword"} -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$URLIndex = "$latestArtifactURL".IndexOf('http:')
$redirectedURL = "$latestArtifactURL".SubString("$URLIndex") 
Invoke-WebRequest $redirectedURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $EncodedPassword"} -Outfile "App.zip"
```

You can also use the webclient to download the file. Hope this helps.